# Черный экран после выхода из игры в виртуальной машине

Tags: pascal, разработка-игр

Снова делаю игру на паскале. Теперь с помощью graph. Работает он только в Windows XP, а у меня Ubuntu. Поэтому приходиться использовать ВМ. Но после выхода из игры, я получаю черный экран. Приходится перезапустить ВМ. Если из TurboPascal я жму Alt+Enter, а потом выхожу, то у меня тот же черный экран. Как с этим справится?

Если я правильно понял, то после выхода из графического режима, я попадаю в текстовый. Как мне вернуться в ГУИшный винды?

Не нужно писать мне "используй другой продукт". Это задание - его тонкости я не выбирал.

Comment: P.S. проблема к программированию имеет посредственное отношение - скорее к использованию программных продуктов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, необходимо использовать соответствующие средства. Если пишете под ДОС - ставьте ДОС. Можно через эмулятор DOSBox.
Во-вторых, любая эмуляция кривая. А по факту у Вас происходит следующее - виртуальная машина под хостовой операционной системой (Ubuntu), в ней - Windows XP. В Windows XP работает NTVDM.EXE - по-простому, эмулятор ДОСа. И работает он иногда весьма криво именно с полноэкранными графическими приложениями. Тем более гадать, где кривость кроется, при том, что не указана программа ВМ, нет желания.
В третьих, хотите графические приложения - освойте какую-нибудь нормальную библиотеку. Graph далеко не лучший выбор. В конце-концов взять Delphi/Lazarus, а затем на форме сделать компонент типа TImage и нарисовать в нем что-либо не так уж и сложно.

Comment: Я пишу курсовую другу, увы в его универе сказали паскаль и все! :)

Comment: Использую последний VirtualBox.

Comment: Молодец, специально заминусовали? Я ж говорю - зависание после графического режима - особенность работы эмуляции DOS в среде Windows NT. Не нравится - ставьте DOSBOX или DOS прямо на виртуалку. Тогда виснуть не будет.